# Is there a way to get the PropertyDrawer-derived class given a type that has been associated with it using CustomPropertyDrawer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a Unity3D script, is there a way to get the `PropertyDrawer`-derived class given the type it's been associated with using `CustomPropertyDrawer`? So in the following example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public struct MyCustomType {
    ...
}

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(MyCustomType))]
public class MyCustomTypeDrawer : PropertyDrawer {
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
        ...
    }
}
```

...this method would return `MyCystomTypeDrawer` (preferably as a `Type`) if given `MyCustomType`. But it would be general and work for any type that has a `PropertyDrawer`-derived class associated with it using `CustomPropertyDrawer`.

Comment: You definitely can using Reflection.  Go through all the loaded assemblies, look through each declared type, and check if the type extends PropertyDrawer.  You will then need to get the Type that was passed to the CustomPropertyDrawerAttribute (internal Type m_Type), then check if that Type is the same as the Type passed in to your function.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @hijinxbassist's comment: here's my implementation:

```
IEnumerable<System.Type> AllPropertyDrawers()
{
    List<System.Type> drawers = new List<Type>();
    foreach (Assembly ass in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        foreach (Type t in ass.GetTypes())
        {
            if (t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(PropertyDrawer)))
            {
                yield return t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
System.Type GetCustomPropertyDrawerFor(System.Type target)
{
    foreach (Type drawer in AllPropertyDrawers())
    {
        foreach (var attribute in Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(drawer))
        {
            if (attribute is CustomPropertyDrawer cpd)
            {
                if (target.IsSubclassOf(cpd.GetPrivateMemberUsingReflection<Type>("m_Type")))
                {
                    return drawer;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And you can easily use the returned type to draw an editorGUI:

```
public static void ShowDefaultPropertyGUI(Rect pos, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label, bool includeChildren = false)
{
    var propertyDrawerType = GetCustomPropertyDrawerFor(property.GetSerializedPropertyType());
    if (propertyDrawerType != null)
    {
        PropertyDrawer drawer = (PropertyDrawer)Activator.CreateInstance(propertyDrawerType);
        pos.height = drawer.GetPropertyHeight(property, label);
        drawer.OnGUI(pos, property, label);
    }
    else
    {
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(pos, property, label, includeChildren);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `GetPrivateMemberUsingReflection`? I get an error saying it's not a member of `CustomPropertyDrawer` and there's no documentation for it.